# send mail with images getting Exception using java

Tags: java, email

I am doing java web application, here I have a class(WishesDAO.java) i need to get the data from data base and send it to another class(SendEmailclass.java) while sending the data i attached text with image also but images not loading properly based on this text and image I need to send mail to every employee. but I am unable to send email with image

WishesDAO.java

```
public  String method()
{
   rs =  stmnt.executeQuery(DOBQuery);
            while(rs.next())//DOB
             {              

                String From="ABC@hai.com";
                String To=rs.getString("Emailid");              
                String Name=rs.getString("Ename");                          
               String htmlText = "<img src=Images/ABC.JPG/>";
                String text="Hi "+Name.toString()+","+"\n\n"+"Happy BirthDay....!"+"\n\n"+htmlText+"\n\nFrom,\nTeam";
                SendEmail stp=new SendEmail();
                stp.mail(From, To,Name,text);
             }
}
```

SendEmail.java:

```
 try {
             // Create a default MimeMessage object.
             MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

             // Set From: header field of the header.
             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(From));

             // Set To: header field of the header.
             message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(To));

             // Set Subject: header field
             message.setSubject("Wishes!", "UTF-8");

             // Now set the actual message

             message.setText(text, "text/html");// getting the text from WishesDAO.java
             // Send message
             Transport.send(message);           
             msg=message.toString();
          }catch (MessagingException mex) {
             mex.printStackTrace();
             System.out.println(mex);
          }
```

I am getting the below Exception:

> javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
>   nested exception is:  java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: text/html
>   javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
>   nested exception is:  java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: text/html
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1167)
>     at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)   at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)     at
>   Model.SendEmail.mail(SendEmail.java:39)   at
>   Model.WishesDAO.method(WishesDAO.java:72)     at
>   Model.Testing.run(Testing.java:24)    at
>   java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: text/html   at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.forOutputStreamWriter(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.OutputStreamWriter.(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain.writeTo(text_plain.java:161)     at
>   javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1574)  at
>   javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1840)    at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1119)
>     ... 7 more

How can I display images with text dynamically

when i use setcontent it mail appears like

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `setContent` not `setText`

```
message.setContent(text, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Not sure based upon your code, but I think you can also be using a MutiPart

see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_send_inlineimage_in_email.htm for a full example.

But the main points are

```
// first part (the html)
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
String htmlText = "<H1>Hello</H1><img src=\"cid:image\">";
messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");
// add it
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

then

```
// second part (the image)
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(
 "/home/manisha/javamail-mini-logo.png");

messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");
```

Next set the multipart in the message as follows:

```
message.setContent(multipart);
```

Comment: Hi,@Scary Wombat, I tried with your code but i am able to send mail the mail format images are not displaying

Comment: When i am taken the `message.setContent(text, "text/html; charset=utf-8");` this method it loads image see updated images code

Comment: Is that a security feature on your email client?

Comment: No security feature

Comment: ,what is this `DataSource fds = new FileDataSource( "/home/manisha/javamail-mini-logo.png");`

Answer (score 0):

setText() method requires Charset encoding type. So, you can use this method as:

```
message.setText(text, "UTF-8");
```

If you want to use text/html, you can do something like this:

```
message.setContent(text, "text/html");
```